# error creating a dataset in Analytics Cloud

Tags: analytics-cloud

I've tried to create a dataset in Analytics Cloud, and keep getting stuck at the same place.  After using the Dataset Builder I go to Data Monitor and Start the default Data Flow.  Regardless of what objects I have included in my dataset, they all fail with the same error:

> [Error executing node 114 [root cause: None of requested fields is
>   available. Aborting.]

Advice?

Comment: did you check if the Integration user profile used by analytics cloud has access to those objects & fields included in your dataset ?

Comment: Yes - I have given the integration user the permission set license and permission sets with access to all the objects/fields.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing the same issue on our org. I reset the ELT script back to a default version without builder input, ran the Data flow Manually, it was successful. I then added some extra objects and various fields to the ELT Data flow via the dataset builder and the flow was successful again.

Below is my "default" version of a ELT JSON, This should work with all orgs:

{
  "100": {
    "action": "sfdcDigest",
    "parameters": {
      "object": "Account",
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "Description"
        },
        {
          "name": "Fax"
        },
        {
          "name": "Id"
        },
        {
          "name": "Name"
        },
        {
          "name": "Phone"
        },
        {
          "name": "AccountSource"
        },
        {
          "name": "Type"
        },
        {
          "name": "AnnualRevenue"
        },
        {
          "name": "BillingCity"
        },
        {
          "name": "BillingCountry"
        },
        {
          "name": "BillingLatitude"
        },
        {
          "name": "BillingLongitude"
        },
        {
          "name": "BillingState"
        },
        {
          "name": "BillingStreet"
        },
        {
          "name": "BillingPostalCode"
        },
        {
          "name": "CreatedDate"
        },
        {
          "name": "Jigsaw"
        },
        {
          "name": "IsDeleted"
        },
        {
          "name": "NumberOfEmployees"
        },
        {
          "name": "Industry"
        },
        {
          "name": "JigsawCompanyId"
        },
        {
          "name": "LastActivityDate"
        },
        {
          "name": "LastModifiedDate"
        },
        {
          "name": "LastReferencedDate"
        },
        {
          "name": "LastViewedDate"
        },
        {
          "name": "PhotoUrl"
        },
        {
          "name": "ShippingCity"
        },
        {
          "name": "ShippingCountry"
        },
        {
          "name": "ShippingLatitude"
        },
        {
          "name": "ShippingLongitude"
        },
        {
          "name": "ShippingState"
        },
        {
          "name": "ShippingStreet"
        },
        {
          "name": "ShippingPostalCode"
        },
        {
          "name": "SicDesc"
        },
        {
          "name": "SystemModstamp"
        },
        {
          "name": "Website"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "101": {
    "action": "sfdcDigest",
    "parameters": {
      "object": "Account",
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "Name"
        },
        {
          "name": "BillingCity"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "102": {
    "action": "sfdcRegister",
    "parameters": {
      "source": "101",
      "alias": "test2",
      "name": "test"
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

Does the referenced object in node 114 have at least one field listed?

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=bi_dataset_builder.htm