# Salesforce Analytics Cloud integration user to import Salesforce data?

Tags: analytics-cloud

The Data Integration Guide says

> “You can run a maximum of 10 dataflow jobs during a rolling 24-hour
>   period. This limit excludes failed jobs.”

I do not have any successful jobs other than 2 CSV uploads and I am getting the message

> “Maximum Daily Analytics Dataflow Executions has been exceeded.
>   Current value is 10, and the limit is 10”

when running dataflow jobs to create a new dataset.

I created a permission set for the Integration User with Edit Analytics Cloud Dataflows permission, assigned the permission set to the user, and I’m getting the error

> “Failed Reason for Failure : Error executing node 110 [root cause:
>   None of requested fields is available. Aborting.]”

whenever I manually run a dataflow job. All I am trying to do is import Opportunity and Account data.

What am I missing? Will someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare your ELT to the one commented here: [error creating a dataset in Analytics Cloud](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/72158/error-creating-a-dataset-in-analytics-cloud).

If you are unsure how to download and compare have a look at the image found here: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=bi_integrate_dataflow_run.htm&language=en_US

I have seen this issue a few times, I have seen it relate to the following:

- Null in the naming of the generating dataset
- No sfdcregister step

Unsure on the 10 unsuccessful count on the ELT Workflow. Do a ticket to Salesforce. I haven't noticed this as an issue previously.

Comment: Thank you @AndrewPrice. For some reason the name of all datasets I try to create are set to null despite indicating a name when creating the datasets. Manually updating the JSON worked.